# Images in AS3 Array

Tags: actionscript-3

How can i put the follow images in to an array so i can call them like myBlock[1], myBlock[2] etc etc

```
var myBlock1:Block = new Block();
var myBlock2:Block = new Block();
var myBlock3:Block = new Block();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myBlock:Array = new Array(
    new Block(),
    new Block(),
    new Block()
);
```

See [this tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3arrays/) for more array stuff.

Comment: or simply ... `var myBlock = [new Block(), new Block(), new Block()];`

Comment: or even better use a vector: `var myBlock:Vector.<Block> = new <Block>[new Block(), new Block(), new Block()];`

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this.

```
var myBlock:Array = new Array();
myBlock.push(myBlock1, myBlock2, myBlock3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in a nice loop:

```
var blocks:Array = [];
var n:int = 100; // I want a hundred blocks please

for(var i:int = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var block:Block = new Block();
    block.id = i; // my block class has an id 
    blocks.push(block);
{

// I want block 42 - (or 41 as its 0 based to be pedantic)
trace(blocks[41].id); // my block has id of 42
```